# Infected Fish can eat another fish having size less that its own. Minimum number of operation required

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, array-algorithms

An evil scientist has developed an injection that induces insatiable hunger in a fish. On giving this injection, a fish of size x can eat another fish of smaller size y (y < x) and become a fish of size x + y retaining this hunger. An aquarium has a number of fishes of various sizes. The scientist introduces an injected fish into this aquarium with an objective that eventually only 1 fish remains. In order to achieve this, the scientist is allowed only two types of moves: either add a normal fish of any size or remove an existing normal fish from the aquarium. Given the sizes of other fishes in the aquarium and the size of injected fish, write a program to determine the minimum number of moves needed by the scientist to achieve his objective.
For example, suppose there are 5 fishes in the aquarium, the injected fish is of size 10 and the other fishes are of sizes 9, 20, 25, and 100. To ensure that only 1 fish remains in the aquarium the scientist needs to remove the fish of size 100 and add a fish of size 3. So the output is 2. The sequence of steps is shown below. The sizes of fishes in the aquarium at each step are shown in curly braces. The highlighted number is the size of the injected fish.

Input format:
{infectedFish} # {a,b,c,d ... } where a,b,c etc are normal fishs

Example:

- 10#9,20,25,100      ===> 2
- 3#25,20,100,400,500  ===> 5
- 50#25,20,9,100     ===>0

I have used following code to solve the problem.

```
 public static int count(int inf, int a[], int i, int op){

    //base case
    if(i==a.length){
      return op;
    }

    while(i<a.length && inf>a[i]){
      inf+=a[i];
      i++;
    }

    if(i==a.length){
      return op;
    }

    int curr = inf+inf-1;
    return Math.min(count(curr, a, i, op+1), count(inf, a, i+1, op+1));

  }
```

Calling it using, `System.out.println(count(x, a, 0, 0));` x is infected fish and a is given sorted array;

Is this approach correct? If so, seems like its is having comman subproblem, How can we do memoization?

Comment: Maybe something more efficient can be made if you start from the other end (the largest number) and work your way to `infectedFish`.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. If you get a wrong result, please provide corresponding input/output

Comment: Can you please share a link to the online judge?

Comment: I am not able to find online judge link for this question and @Damien I am not sure if this is correct solution, i just test with give example inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the efficiency by slightly modifying your algorithm.

If you have more than one fish to eat, it is not optimal to remove the next one, and then try to eat a fish which is bigger.

When you eat a fish, you become bigger, without any cost.

Therefore, the alternatives are:

- Eat the next fish after growing up, i.e. after adding new fishes
- Get rid of all remaining fishes

Then, the formula can be simplified as follows, other codes remaining unchanged:

```
return Math.min(count(curr, a, i, op+1), op + a.length -1 - i);
```

In this case, you don't need memoization: the `count` function is following one way only, always increasing its internal values.

Note: I assume here that the fishes are sorted, as mentioned in your code.

Complexity, without taking into account sorting: `O(n + log(weight_max/weigth_in))`

EDIT: there is another way to speed up the process:

If, at a given time, the number of operation `op` is greater than the current optimum value, then you can stop the recursion.

Comment: I did not run the code but I think your code provides the good result. The modification I propose speeds up the process, but provides the same result

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, greedy can work here. After first eating all smaller fish, each choice point is (1) add the largest possible fish smaller than the current hungry fish, or (2) remove all equal or larger fish. Clearly, removing a fish from the middle is unnecessary since if we could consume a larger one, we could consume that one as well.

The state we would like to optimise is `num_current_moves + num_removals_needed`. But since we only need a single variable to store the best seen such state, we can update it after every choice, iterating up the sorted list, greedily adding fish. Choice (2) isn't an active change; rather, it's just part of calculating the best seen state at each point.

Iterative JavaScript code:

```js
function f(x, A){
  A.sort((a, b) => a - b)
  
  let sum = x
  let removals_needed = A.length
  let moves = 0
  let best = removals_needed
  let i = 0
  
  while (i < A.length){
    if (sum > A[i]){
      sum = sum + A[i]
      removals_needed = removals_needed - 1
      i = i + 1

    // It might not be worth
    // trying to grow the fish,
    // but the growth rate is 
    // probably fast enough not
    // to add significant time
    } else {
      sum = sum + (sum - 1)
      moves = moves + 1
    }
    
    best = Math.min(best, moves + removals_needed)
  }
  
  return best
}

var inputs = [
  [10, [9,20,25,100]], // 2
  [3, [25,20,100,400,500]], // 5
  [3, [20,21,22,23,24,25]], // 4
  [3, [20,21,22]], // 3
  [50, [25,20,9,100]] // 0
]

for (let [x, A] of inputs){
  console.log(`${x} -> ${A}`)
  console.log(f(x, A))
  console.log("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's summarize:

There are two possible interventions:
Remove biggest fish, and
Add a fish just smaller than the infected fish.

The infected fish can gobble up all smaller fishes, each time growing by the eaten fish's size.

You want the minimum number of interventions to leave only the devourer.

---

A far simpler algorithm is:

1. Sort all normal fishes by size.
2. The trivial solution is removing all fishes manually.
3. You have not yet added any new fishes.
4. Gobble up the smallest fishes as long as possible.
5. New candidate solution is fishes added plus fishes remaining. Choose the better one.
6. If no fishes left, you are done.
7. Grow the devourer to 2*size-1 by adding a fish of size size-1 as often as needed to devour the smallest fish.
8. Contine with step 4, devouring fishes.

Answer (score 0):

I will make 2 changes to this solution :
1.) Since I didn't see in the question that the Killer fish cannot be of size = 0.
Or of size 1.
I will add that condition to avoid possible infinite loop.

2.)
You are calculating cost on the number of recursions = for increasing the size of fish (SI) + for removing the fish (RF).
I don't see how SI is related to N or

E.g.

N = 100,000 = 10^6

A = [ 10^7, 10^5 + 10^7, 10^6 + 10^8, ........ ] // For actually large size example

If the Infected fish was of size 2.
And the next possible fish it can eat is say 10,000,000.
And total number of fishes are as 10^6.

Now the SI would be recurs-ing over 2, 3, 5, 8..... K etc.
K > 10,000,000

Just to see what is cost/count to make it actually greater than the next possible candidate fish that can be eaten.

So I would not use recursion to calculate that.
I would use simply this logic

cost or count = Ceiling { Ln[(F-1)/(K-1)] }  // O(1)

// F = Weight of fish greater than infected fish - at the moment of recursion.

// K - Infected Fish's current weight.

// Ln - Log to the base 2.

// Ceiling will give us the Rounded off value e.g. ceiling (3.4) = 4, ceiling (3.7) = 4.

Now the running cost is simply O(n), if not including the cost for sorting.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int HungryFish(int infectedFishSize, int[] fishs)
    {
        Array.Sort(fishs);
        int moves = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < fishs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fishs[i] < infectedFishSize)
            {
                infectedFishSize += fishs[i];
            }
            else
            {
                if (fishs[i] < (infectedFishSize + infectedFishSize - 1))
                {
                    infectedFishSize += (infectedFishSize - 1);
                    moves++;
                }
                else
                {
                    moves += (fishs.Length - i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return moves;
    }
```